# Роутинг сложного запроса ASP .NET MVC Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Имеется роутинг вида `/api/Projects/1`, т.е. для контроллера Project будет послан запрос GET (или ещё какой) с параметром `1`.
В связи с использованием dhtmlxGantt, нужно сделать обработку запросов вида:
`api/Projects/1/task/7` (диаграмма Ганта формирует запросы вида `task/7` на указанный адрес, который в данном случае `api/Projects/1`)

Answer (score 0):

По-идее должно быть что-то такое

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}/task/{taskId:int}")]
public IActionResult Get(int id, int taskId)
{...}
```

, но я не проверял, хотя должно сработать.

Answer (score 0):

Использовал в итоге такое

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Projects/{projectId}/Task/{id}")]
    public IActionResult Get(int projectId,int id)
```

Comment: Вот это `api/Projects` надо бы над классом контроллера навесить, чтоб не повторять в каждом экшене.